# Importing two dmp files into single schema

Tags: oracle, dump

I have two dmp files to imported into the same schema in my DB. They are each 20GB (size was probably the reason why they were exported as two dump files). How can I do a successive import into the schema. Does impdp command have an option to allow me to import more than one file?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just run the import twice? I am assuming the files have disjoint sets of data. You may need a command line switch "ignore=y" to allow the import to continue if the objects it's trying to create already exist.

Or, perhaps I'm not understanding your situation fully.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used DataPump, but it looks like you can just give multiple filenames separated by commas.  Look here at the DUMPFILE parameter:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1010670